# YouTube not working on Apple TV

Tags: appletv, youtube

I cant view YouTube  on Apple TV I only see the loading circle any suggestion on how to fix it would be appreciated

Comment: I suddenly have this problem too. By any chance, is ATT U-Verse your ISP?

Answer (score 1):

Try go into General and restart, This worked for me.